# REGEXP_SUBSTR equivalent in HIVE SQL?

Tags: sql, regex, hive, hiveql, regexp-substr

Good morning.  I am looking for the equivalent in Hive of REGEXP_SUBSTR, which I use in other databases like Teradata.

My specific case is:  I have a field that has a string.  It looks something like this:

```
Row1: ABC ACC ADF AFA BAC CAF
Row2: ACC BAC CAG HOL HRR NOM
Row3: ACC ARR BBA CAF LOM NOM
```

In my WHERE clause, I am using RLIKE to look for specific parts of the string, like:

WHERE mystring RLIKE 'BAC|BBA'

What I'd like to do is also return whichever part matched as a column.  So the result would be:

```
Row1: BAC
Row2: BAC
Row3: BBA
```

In other databases, I would do this by putting this in the SELECT statement: REGEXP_SUBSTR(mystring,'(BAC|BBA)\S*').  Is there an equivalent function in Hive?  If so, what is the syntax?

I've looked at a few different Hive functions but they seem to expect the string to be in the same place each time, which is not the case here.  But I admittedly could be misunderstanding the syntax.

Comment: The function is called `regexp_extract()` in Hive.

Answer (score 3):

Use regexp_extract and double-slash for special chars like \s:

```
 select regexp_extract('ABC ACC ADF AFA BAC CAF','(BAC|BBA)\\s*');
```

Read more about syntax here: [Hive Language Manual - StringFunctions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions)

Comment: Seems to work perfectly, thank you so much for the syntax example!!